# how can play with the text inside a form submit button?

Tags: html, css, web

how can play with the text inside a form submit button, the text inside is align in the bottom how can i centered?

I had try many functions like align, align vertical, margin.

```
form .submit{
     background: white;
     border-color: transparent;
     color:black;
     font-size: 4vw;
     width: 60px;
     height: 25px;
     bottom: -15vh;
     left: 40vw;
     vertical-align: -5px;
     font-family: 'athela', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

[the sende button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3f83.jpg)

Comment: please share some of your HTML code

Comment: a quick fix would be "line-height: 25px;", but it will only work if it has only one row of text. Alternatively, remove the height and give some padding-top and padding-bottom

Comment: Either do @JonasGrumann's answer, or remove the `height` and adjust the size with `padding` instead.

Comment: Do not give height width to button, instead use padding to increase its size .Remove height,width and add padding: 8px 12px;

Comment: You can play around display or a mix of padding/line-height . codepen to play with : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NVdLQL (examples with padding/line-height/inline-grid/inline-flex/table-cell .. the default display of button is inline-block to start with ;)

Answer (score 1):

To center the text, you can make the submit button a flex box.

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button>send</button>
```

Comment: I think in this case flexbox is not a good solution (even it works), because you can obtain the same result with line-height:25px; and text-align :center.

Comment: @Sfili_81 `line-height` is hack-ish, which will cause problems. Flex is the proper or more appropriate way to do it. You'll run into problems using `line-height` if you ever change the `font-size` or `height` of the element.

Comment: You're right, but so you can remove width and height and use padding to center the text. In my opinion this is not the case to use flexbox.

Comment: Or if you break a sentence  (e.g. due to overflow). I would not know the best solution here as I think flexbox does not exist to solve such a problem, but I also think `line-height` would not be the effective solution. Flexbox is good for aligning 'block-level' elements around for as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Sfili_81 Using padding to center the element will change the dimensions of the element, which the original poster may not want to do...

Comment: @Barrosy Flex box is perfect for something like this. It doesn't matter whether you're aligning block elements or not. There's literally no downside of using flex in this situation, yet there's downsides or potentially unwanted side effects from basically every other method :/

Comment: in the original poster you can use line-height instead flexbox. For padding you can use box-sizing property. But i'll repeat it's only my opinion. In this case i won't use a flexbox to align the text inside a button.

Comment: @Sfili_81 There is no problem with using flexbox for this and it will make it far more maintainable and resilient to changes than if you used fixed values like pixels for line-height and padding. The bare minimum you should be using is rem or em units.

Comment: @Coffeebean amen. there are drawbacks of every other approach. flex box is by far the cleanest and most manageable.

Answer (score 0):

use line height to solve your problem

```css
body{
  background: #666;
}

button {
  background: white;
     border-color: transparent;
     color:black;
     font-size: 4vw;
     width: 60px;
     height: 25px;
     padding: 0;
     line-height: 24px;
     font-family: 'athela', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```